# Repeatable annotations in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

```
// Demonstrate a repeated annotation.

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

// Make MyAnno repeatable.
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(MyRepeatedAnnos.class)
@interface MyAnno {
    String str() default "Testing";
    int val() default 9000;
}

// This is the container annotation.
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyRepeatedAnnos {
    MyAnno[] value();
}

class RepeatAnno {

    // Repeat MyAnno on myMeth().
    @MyAnno(str = "First annotation", val = -1)
    @MyAnno(str = "Second annotation", val = 100)
    public static void myMeth(String str, int i) {
        RepeatAnno ob = new RepeatAnno();
        try {
            Class<?> c = ob.getClass();
            // Obtain the annotations for myMeth().
            Method m = c.getMethod("myMeth", String.class, int.class);
            // Display the repeated MyAnno annotations.
            Annotation anno = m.getAnnotation(MyRepeatedAnnos.class);
            System.out.println(anno);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
            System.out.println("Method Not Found.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        myMeth("test", 10);
    }
}
```

I have copy-pasted this code from a book and I tried to run this code in my system with JDK version *1.8.0_131*, but I'm getting the following compilation error:

> ```
> error: cannot find symbol
> @Repeatable(MyRepeatedAnnos.class)
>  ^
>   symbol: class Repeatable
> RepeatAnno.java:19: error: duplicate annotation
> @MyAnno(str = "Second annotation", val = 100)
> ^
> 2 errors
> ```

I can't understand what is wrong here.
Please help.

Comment: Works fine for me when compiling with IntelliJ and with `javac` (also 1.8.0_131 on Linux). Are you using IDE or compiling it from terminal? Maybe your default java is 1.7?

Comment: @jereksel yeah I checked. Turns out my java version is 1.8.0_131 but javac version is 1.7.0_79. Thanks for reminding.